# How to access Google search right hand side data programmatically?

Tags: google-api, screen-scraping, web-scraping, semantics

Is there a way to access data on the right hand side of Google results programmatically?

Are there similar services around? Specifically for location data

**Access = No html scraping**

Here is an example: 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 2018 Update - [Knowledge Panels](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6331288?hl=en)

> When people search for a business on Google, they may see information about that business in a box that appears to the right of their search results. The information in the box, called the knowledge panel, can help customers discover and contact your business.
>
> [image: Knowledge Panel Example]
>
> Knowledge panels are powered by information in the Knowledge Graph.

---

### Google's Knowledge Graph

The example in your question comes from [Google's Knowledge Graph](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/introducing-knowledge-graph-things-not.html).

[The Short Life of the Open Knowledge Graph](https://web.archive.org/web/20130329151128/http://zecblog.com/2012/09/16/the-short-life-of-the-open-knowledge-graph/) provides a good explanation why Google's Knowledge Graph data is not publicly available and why the project is shutting down.

> [Jack Menzel, a Product Management Director at Google,] explained that there was a couple of specific
>   reasons why Google couldn’t “participate” in the Open Knowledge Graph
>   project. First, some of the data in the Google Knowledge Graph are
>   from closed datasets acquired from sources that did not granted Google
>   the rights to redistribute them. Some other datasets have more open
>   licenses, but still have share-alike or attribution constraints.
>   Second, he reminded that – by principle – Google was blocking any kind
>   of automatic extraction allowing to collect information about its
>   search and ranking technologies because “they were the proprietary
>   cores of what Google provides”.

### Alternative Solutions

I tried to list in order of your preference for location data.

- **Freebase** -
  http://www.freebase.com/ will provide you with the same type of information and allow you to achieve the same type of results as your Google search example.

  > **Freebase** is an open, [Creative Commons](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Creative_Commons) licensed repository of
  >   [structured data](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Structured_data) of almost 23 million [entities](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Entity).
  >
  > An **entity** is a single
  >   person, place, or thing. Freebase connects entities together as a
  >   [graph](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Graph).
- **Wikidata** -
  http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page - Wikidata is an open source project, and the data is freely accessible
- **YAGO** - http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/

  > YAGO2s is a huge semantic knowledge base, derived from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/), [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), and [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/).
- **Wolfram Alpha** - http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/

Comment: IG just b/c this is old response, but it's 2018 and the _Knowledge Panels_ are still running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google knowledge graph API for this

- create an application in google developers console
- create authentication credentials

  ```
   knowlegdegraph<-function(query)
  {
     API_Key<-"YOUR_API_KEY"
     url<-paste("https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=",query, 
       "&key=", API_Key,
       "&limit=1&indent=True")
    jdata <- fromJSON(URLencode(url))

  }
  ```

  Jdata is a list. you can extract the JSON element for location from it

Comment: Results returned by knowledge API are different than the knowledge panel I get from google search result. Is there anyway to get the same knowledge panel details from knowledge API?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a budget, you may consider [serpapi.com](https://serpapi.com/), a Google Search API provider which performs real-time Google search and returns the result as JSON.

A sample search of the keyword "Coffee" via the API would return the full SERP parameters and metadatas of the search result. The partial "knowledge panel" metadatas for the sample search is returned as followed:

```
"knowledge_graph": {
    "title": "Coffee",
    "image": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",
    "description": "Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain Coffea species. The genus Coffea is native to tropical Africa and Madagascar, the Comoros, Mauritius, and Réunion in the Indian Ocean.",
    "source": {
      "name": "Wikipedia",
      "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee"
    },
    "countries_of_origin": "Yemen (drink), Ethiopia (plant)",
    "coffee_companies": [
      {
        "name": "Starbucks",
        "link": "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&q=Starbucks&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVAjMNLZLji7REspOt9JPzc3Pz86xS8svzyhOLUopXMQoDxXJyUpNLMvPz9DOLi0tTi4oXsXIGlyQWJZUmZxcDANn7PURQAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPi5uzxvDhAhXHu54KHXouArgQxA0wJnoECBIQBQ",
        "source": "common"....
```

[image: Comparison between the search result and the JSON result]